# How to use broadcast to receive and send data between two activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-broadcast

I have two different activities.

In the first activity, i click a button and then send broadcast.

Second activity can receive the broadcast, and do next event.

**How to use dynamic register broadcast to do this?**

Comment: You send data from one `Activity` to another by using `Intent` extras and calling `startActivity(...)` with that `Intent`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple activities running at the same time, so your `BroadcastReceiver` have to be outside that class like in [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm) tutorial.

Once your `BroadcastReceiver` has been triggered you can launch your second activity, using certain parameters in order to know that you have to trigger a second event.

Nevertheless, another possible solution could be opening directly your second activity from the button click , dont you think?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to pass information between two activities is with the use of Intent.
Read this - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(key, value);
startActivity(intent);
```

On the SecondActivity you get the information like this -

```
int x = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(key)
```

You cannot use BroadcastReceiver to pass vars between activities because they don't run in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to broadcast data from one activity to another, simply make use of Intent. In the `onDestroy` method of your second activity create Intent object and broadcast data as intent extra then, use `intent.getExtra()` method on `onReceive()` method of your `broadcastReceiver` class.

For more details:
[follow this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqU97bQ54B4)

Answer (score -1):

You need to Change Manifest file you need to add following code

```
<receiver android:name="MyScheduleReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="MyStartServiceReceiver" >
        </receiver>
```

Second Thing is Sending Activity and Reaching activity

Sending:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
            //do your stuff
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Receiving:

```
public class MyReceiver extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

    }


}
```